# Signing certificate request with certificate authority created in openssl

Tags: openssl, certificates

I created a certificate authority in Ubuntu using this command:

```
openssl req -config /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf -new -x509 -keyout ck.pem -out cacert.pem -days 365
```

Then I created a certificate request using:

```
openssl req -out C.csr -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout c_p.key
```

I would like to sign this request using the certificate authority I created. For that I executed:

```
openssl ca -config /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf -policy optional -out C.crt -infiles C.csr
```

But I get the error:

> ```
> Using configuration from /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf unable to load CA
> private key 140189274035872:error:0906D06C:PEM
> routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:pem_lib.c:703:Expecting: ANY
> PRIVATE KEY
> ```

How can I get rid of this error? Will this command use the authority I defined above or maybe some default authority in the system?

**EDIT:**

For completeness I leave the steps that I had to do:

1. Create the relevant files:

> ```
> mkdir demoCA
> mkdir ./demoCA/newcerts
> touch ./demoCA/index.txt
> ```

Also create a "serial" file in demoCA that contains 01 and a newline at the end.

2. Certify:

> ```
> openssl ca -config /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf -cert cacert.pem -keyfile ck.pem -out C.crt -infiles C.csr
> ```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've created a new key pair with the first command.  You now need to tell the OpenSSL CA about these.

Either edit `/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf` and ensure that the `private_key` and `certificate` lines point to the new private key and certificate file locations, or use the `-cert` and `-keyfile` arguments to the `openssl ca` command to override the values in `/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf`.